# Using Flexform settings in FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject content element

Tags: typo3, extbase, fluid-styled-content

I’m migrating an Extbase content element to a FLUIDTEMPLATE cObj CE with dataprocessors.
One problem I step into are Flexform + TypoScript settings.
With Extbase I got a merged settings array of TypoScript and Flexform, with FLUIDTEMPLATE I just get the TypoScript.

I use Flexform and TypoScript settings e.g. to configure a slider:

```
<div class="slider" data-slick='{settings.slider.slick -> e:format.json.encode()}'>
```

Comment: You can write a custom implementation of the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\DataProcessorInterface` and use it in your fluidcontent dataprocessor config like `10 = MyNamespace\DataProcessing\FlexformProcessor`. Inside the processor you can easily read and convert your flexform using the cObj-Object and `GeneralUtility::xml2array`.

Comment: Example FlexFormProcessor: https://github.com/t3kit/t3kit_extension_tools/blob/master/Classes/DataProcessing/FlexFormProcessor.php

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the example provided by stmllr and made some changes that makes it act like the Extbase FrontendConfigurationManager https://gist.github.com/t3easy/22bdcf7189e0dce76e246a581790e4a4

Main change is, that just FlexForm prefixed with `settings.` are merged with TypoScript settings. And that I use `ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule`.
Hope that helps others to migrate.